# Words for previous or next day for an organisation

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Curious if there are words for yesterday or tomorrow in an organisation sense.  If an organisation works Monday to Friday the weekend days would be excluded. One could refer to previous or next working day or subsitute the word working for business. I'm interested if there is a single word to achieve this.

Comment: Depending on the context and formality, generally either "the next/previous work day" or "the next/previous business day" would be used in the US.  No single word for either direction.

Comment: @HotLicks The same applies in British English. I know of no simpler expression.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a *single* word to my knowledge. The usual phrase for these is *Business Day*. The previous Friday is the previous business day. On Friday the next Monday is the following or next business day.

Comment: This answer implies the answer is No; it may be better to state that explicitly.